# Cannot change pages while adding data to DataTables table

Tags: javascript, datatables

I have a dataTables table and adding large chunk of of rows into it.
I'd like to be able working with table while data being added.

The problem is DataTables code rebuilds the Pagination block at the each `.draw()` execution, doesn't matter what parameters were passed to the function.

Currently, I partially resolved that by "hacking" into the `aoDrawCallback` list and intercepting the `pagination` callback. While adding rows, I allow pagination block to be redrawn when page number or total number of pages changed.

The `await sleep(..);` block provides 2 features:

- It allows table to be redrawn during `for` loop execution;
- It delays code enough, so user is able to click pagination buttons before they are redrawn (even considering that now we redraw them 10 times less frequently - depending of the `show X entries` value)

Depending of table complexity, the sleep value (in milliseconds) could be reduced down to 1.

See code below and in [JSFIddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nsmcan/e5swg07f/)

A deficiency of my solution is that we wasting sleep time on the each loop.
Could you offer any better solution there?

Thanks.

```js
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

var oldPaginationCb;
var prevPage=-1, prevPages=-1;
var isCustomPaginationEnabled = false; //Our custom actions are disabled by default

function myPaginationCb ( settings ) {
  var
      start      = settings._iDisplayStart,
      len        = settings._iDisplayLength,
      visRecords = settings.fnRecordsDisplay(),
      all        = len === -1,
      page = all ? 0 : Math.ceil( start / len ),
      pages = all ? 1 : Math.ceil( visRecords / len );
  if (! (isCustomPaginationEnabled && page === prevPage && pages === prevPages)) {
      prevPage = page;
      prevPages = pages;
      return oldPaginationCb(settings);
  }
}

console.log('started');
var values = [...Array(500).keys()]

var commentTable = $('.commentTable').DataTable();

var dtApi = $('.commentTable').dataTable();

//Replacing the pagination draw callback function
var paginationCallback = dtApi.fnSettings().aoDrawCallback.filter(cb => { return cb.sName === "pagination" })[0];
oldPaginationCb = paginationCallback.fn;
paginationCallback.fn = myPaginationCb;


$('.addComment').on('click', async function () {
    isCustomPaginationEnabled = true;
    for(var i=0; i<values.length; i++) {
        commentTable.row.add(
            [
                'Date',
                'User',
                i,
            ]
        ).draw(false);
        await sleep(50);
    }
    isCustomPaginationEnabled = false;
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<div><strong>
Click Start, then try using the table navigation buttons
</strong></div>
<button class="addComment">
Start
</button>
<table class='commentTable'>
  <thead>
   <th>Date</th>
    <th>User</th>
    <th>Comment</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call [`draw()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/draw()) API method only once outside of `for` loop. For example:

```
for(var i=0; i<values.length; i++) {
   commentTable.row.add(
      [
         'Date',
         'User',
         i,
      ]
   );
}
commentTable.draw();
```

Per [official documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/api/draw()):

> A draw is not performed automatically by most DataTables API actions to allow grouping of actions (for example adding multiple rows is more efficient if you group them).

See [updated example](https://jsfiddle.net/mtcysejq/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: It looks good for 500 records for a simple table. Put there 50,000 instead, add columns and rendering complexity - and you will see a difference.

Comment: @SergeyNudnov, I would also look into using [`deferRender`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/deferRender) option to speed up adding new rows. See [this example](https://datatables.net/extensions/scroller/examples/initialisation/large_js_source.html) for demonstration.

Comment: @SergeyNudnov, also for that many records I would consider looking into server-side processing.